# Collapsing home folder in path to tilde character

Tags: ruby, path, tilde-expansion

In Swift, [`abbreviatingWithTildeInPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407943-abbreviatingwithtildeinpath) creates “a new string that replaces the current home directory portion of the current path with a tilde (~) character”. In other words, it turns `/Users/username/Desktop/` into `~/Desktop`.

In Ruby we can do the reverse with `File.expand_path`:

```
File.expand_path('~/Desktop')
# => /Users/username/Desktop/
```

But there’s seemingly no native way to abbreviate a path with a tilde. I’m achieving it with:

```
'/Users/username/Desktop/'.sub(/^#{ENV['HOME']}/, '~')
```

That seems to work reliably, but are there any flaws I’m missing? Or better yet, is there a native method?

Comment: I can see a problem with the `sub`: `/Users/usernameX/Desktop` might get converted to `~X/Desktop`

Comment: There's also `File.join`. I don't think it expands like `expand_path` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several subtle issues with your approach

1. `Dir.home` is a more reliable way to get the home directory in case the script is running a weird environment
2. home directory names can contain regex special characters, namely `.`, which might cause false positives in a regex. Fixed with `Regexp.escape`
3. the path may be *only* the home directory with no trailing slash. Fixed with a positive lookahead for the end of the string or a separator
4. windows paths might use backslashes. Fixed with File::SEPARATOR
5. Ruby regexs are multiline, in which case `^` and `$` will find the *first line* that matches, not just the start of the string. Fixed with `\A` and `\Z`, though realistically you should never be passing multiline strings to this method

```rb
def File.collapse_path path
  path.sub /\A#{Regexp.escape Dir.home}(?=\Z|#{File::SEPARATOR})/, ?~
end
```